# Symfony 2 Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony

I looked up some solutions, but none of the found fit my problem.

In one controller i create an instance of another controller

```
//Controller1
$mailController = new MailController();
$mailController->newCommentMail($entity, $em);
```

In the MailController i want to generate an URL and send an email

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('path', array('turnId' => $data->getPoi()->getId(), 'poiId' => $data->getPoi()->getTurn()->getId()));
$this->get('mailer')->send($mail);
```

This two lines are throwing the following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

But my IDE indentifies that `$this` is an instance of a controller.

Is there a problem with generating an instance of a Controller like that or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your `$this->get('mailer')` is the line spitting out that error? `$this` could only be a non-object if you were calling this OUTSIDE of an object method.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I can't explain why that is so, it is still in the context of the controller

Comment: That or one of the `$data->` chains is failing, because the intermediate calls aren't returning `$this`.

Comment: I don't even get to the point of `$data`, the error is thrown immediately after `$this->generateUrl`/`$this->get()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your controller as service, then get it in another controller.

In your `services.yml` define needed controller as a service:

```
services:
    your_service_name:
        class: YourCompany\YourBundle\Controller\YourController
```

Then in any controller you'll be able to get this service via container:

```
$yourController = $this->get('your_service_name');
```

---

There is some useful information about [Controllers as Services](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/controller/service.html) in documentation

**Note from OP**

This answer is totally right, i just want to add something so this Answer works to 100% fine!

After i changed the Controller to a Service the service container was missing, refering to [this Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904180/symfony-2-calling-non-existent-service-router).

To set the container, and with that the fully funcionality of SF2, you need to add one line to the service.yml

```
services:
    mail_controller:
        class: YourCompany\YourBundle\Controller\YourController
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ]]
```

Comment: I did this right now, but it changed nothing, still the same error on the same position

Comment: are you sure $this->get('mailer')->send($mail) is the error ?

Comment: Both lines are throwing this error, because both contain `$this`. That's the source of the error

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->container->get('mailer');
```

works?

Comment: Yes, it's working now. The problem was that the `container` was missing

Answer (score 0):

faced this issue...but adding this in the controller service solved it for me

```
calls:
    - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```