# Symfony 2 calling non-existent service "router"

Tags: php, symfony

I have a service `MailController` which is defined like this in my config

```
services:
    mail_controller:
        class: Company\Project\Bundle\Controller\MailController
```

I'm calling the Service in other services

```
$mailController = $this->get('mail_controller');
```

Now the error i get is building up on [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889961/symfony-2-error-call-to-a-member-function-get-on-a-non-object)

The `container` wasn't set on the Controller, so i'm injecting one within the `constructor`

```
// MailController    
public function __construct() {
    $this->setContainer(new Container());
}
```

Now i'm getting this error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "router".
```

I'm guessing that i need to inject further services whatsoever, but i don't know what to inject, so what do i need to further add so my Controller can work with all services?

My MailController looks like this

```
namespace Company\Project\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MailController extends Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setContainer(new Container());
    }

    //Code for mailstuff

}
```

Comment: Is your controller class extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`? Why are you using a controller as a service?

Comment: Yes, of course, the `setContainer` function comes from the Controller Class of Symfony :) Added the Controller to my Question

Comment: Have you read this ~ http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new container rather than injecting the built container so it has no services.

To use your controller you need to inject the pre made service container in to your controller through your service like so..

```
services:
    mail_controller:
        class: Company\Project\Bundle\Controller\MailController
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ]]
```

.. and get rid of the setter in your `__construct`.

Comment: You're my hero! Works perfectly and totally smooth!

Answer (score 1):

injecting the whole service container

```
calls: - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ]]
```

defeats the purpose of declaring your controller as a service.
Just inject the service(s) you need in your constructor. The constructor needs the service handed as an parameter and do not extend `Controller` anymore.

```
//MailController
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface; 
class MailController
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router){
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    //actions
}
```

Now you need to adjust your `services.yml` and extend the service with arguments describing the service you need

```
services:
    mail_controller:
        class: Company\Project\Bundle\Controller\MailController
        arguments:
           - @router
```

et voila,
only one service needed, only one service injected.
If you find yourself injecting too many services in one action, chances are your action/controller is not 'thin' enough.